# Passing the value of current image of the carousel on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, carousel

I have created in a carousel in my asp.net application.
On my button click, i need to pass the current value of the image or label text of the current image displayed. As each image needs to be redirected to different pages.

Is there a way to do that ?

If so please help.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[1] { new DataColumn("ImageUrl") });
                dt.Rows.Add("Images/Airport/airport@3x.png");
                dt.Rows.Add("Images/preFlight/preFlight@3x.png");
                dt.Rows.Add("Images/inFlight/inFlight@3x.png");

                dt.Rows.Add("Images/postFlight/postFlight@3x.png");
                Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Comment: it's unclear what you want to do. Can you provide some code of the button and carousel that would make it easier to understand?

Comment: Consider there are two image is in the carousal, say first image is Peter and second is Tony. If i click the next button based on the image displayed it takes to the next page. If Peter is displayed on the screen on clicking next buttton , it should display pete's details, when Tony is displayed, the next page should display Tony's detials

Comment: Why a button? You could do something like this `<a href="NextPage.aspx?photo=<%= NextPageFromCodeBehind %>">Next Page</a>`

Comment: Sorry VDWWD, I need a common button for a carousel images. Image should not have a hyperlink

Comment: @VDWWD I just need to access the each datarow,whenerver image is changed. I am unable to access. Please help